# How to define the name of the table in shp2pgsql

Tags: shapefile, shp2pgsql

I use shp2pgsql to append a shapefile to an existing table.

How can I define the table where I want to append the shapefile in PostGIS?

This is the command I execute with Python:

```
command = "shp2pgsql -s 4326 -a shape_file.shp | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d gis_exercise -U postgres"
```

But this commands generates a table with the name of the shapefile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add the schemaname and tablename to the command. Like this:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4326 -I [naam].shp [schemaname].[tablename]  | psql -h [host] -d [database] -U [user]
```